# How to save a Tensorflow.js model?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I would like to make a user interface that creates,saves and trains tensorflow.js models. But i can't save a model after creating it. I even copied this code from the tensorflow.js documenation but it does't work:

```js
const model = tf.sequential(
     {layers: [tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [3]})]});
console.log('Prediction from original model:');
model.predict(tf.ones([1, 3])).print();

const saveResults = await model.save('localstorage://my-model-1');

const loadedModel = await tf.loadModel('localstorage://my-model-1');
console.log('Prediction from loaded model:');
loadedModel.predict(tf.ones([1, 3])).print();
```

I always get the error message "*Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"* .How can I fix this? thanks!

Comment: if you run your own code snippet here you can see @Sebastian Speitel's answer

Answer (score 5):

You need to be in an async environment. Either create an async function (`async function name(){...}`) and call it when you need to or the shortest way would be a self invoking async arrow function:

```
(async ()=>{
   //you can use await in here
})()
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an async function and invoke it:

```
async function main() {
  const model = tf.sequential({
    layers: [tf.layers.dense({ units: 1, inputShape: [3] })]
  });
  console.log("Prediction from original model:");
  model.predict(tf.ones([1, 3])).print();

  const saveResults = await model.save("localstorage://my-model-1");

  const loadedModel = await tf.loadModel("localstorage://my-model-1");
  console.log("Prediction from loaded model:");
  loadedModel.predict(tf.ones([1, 3])).print();
}

main();
```